# Constraint with Sql statement

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables

1.`Sales_Items`

2.`Stock_Items`

I want to make sure that when any item is inserted in `sale_items` table then it's `qty` must be less than (`Stock_Items.qty-Sales_Items.Qty`),if this condition is not true then insertion should fail and throw an exception.

How should i do this?Do I need to use sql constraint with expression or Sql triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done using both triggers and constraint. **I would choose a constraint for the specific scenario.**

This is because the triggers are actually used when you want to **do** something **actively** on the moment of the insert/update/delete, like adding or updating another row. In your scenario,  you don't actually need a trigger. Your scenario is the definition of the constraint need. The only reason to use a trigger is if you want to throw a custom error message.

See [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) as a reference for constraints.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Even it is possible to enforce business rules with triggers, you can use CHECK CONSTRAINT with user defined function:

```
ALTER TABLE sales_items
ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK (qty < dbo.udfCheckAvailableStock(YourProductIdColumn, qty))
```

I would use a trigger in case you need to update Stock_Items when a new row is added in Sales_Items.

> Triggers can enforce restrictions that are more complex than those
>   defined with CHECK constraints. Unlike CHECK constraints, triggers can
>   reference columns in other tables. For example, a trigger can use a
>   SELECT from another table to compare to the inserted or updated data
>   and to perform additional actions, such as modify the data or display
>   a user-defined error message.

[See source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214450%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)